# Android : Implementing order progress tracking

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi i am working on a order progress tracking module in my application. When a user books a service it is accepted by our service provider and then service provider keeps updating the status as the events occurs.

I am using firebase notification for realtime updates of the status. But, there are various scenarios where the notification is not received and hence the status is not updated.

So in that case should i use polling every 1 min to fetch status.
Or what are the other ways order tracking is implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

Polling can be optimised further based on your use case:
Poll only when there is an active order and it has been more than a min since the last push was received.

If it is feasible for you change the backend infrastructure, you can probably look into Firebase real time database as it syncs with the client in real time and ensures that both, client and server are in sync.